# Running a Jasmine test suite in Phantom.js without a server

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I am trying to get Phantom.js to run a suite of JavaScript tests written in Jasmine. Here are steps to reproduce what I am doing:

- Get the [latest standalone release](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases) of the latest release of Jasmine framework (a zip archive)
- The archive contains sample specs of a couple of javascript files and the `SpecRunner.html` file that can run these specs in the browser
- Install phantom.js and download [jasmine 2 runner](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-jasmine2.js) from the example folder of phantom.js project
- Try to run `SpecRunner.html` with phantom.js:

  `phantomjs ./phantom/run-jasmine2.js ./jasmine/SpecRunner.html`

*(where `./phantom/run-jasmine2.js` is the path to jasmine2 runner for phantom.js, and `./jasmine/SpecRunner.html` is the path to the spec runner with sample specs in the jasmine folder)*

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.querySelector('.description').innerText')

Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "about". Protocols must match.
```

So it seems like Phantom is unhappy that the spec runner is provided to it directly as a file from the disk, and not as a file served by a local server (`localhost:8080/SpecRunner.html`). Could you suggest a way to make Phantom work with the spec runner file without spinning up a server? And also without Karma, if possible.

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example here of a working [Karma, PhantomJS, Jasmine setup](https://gist.github.com/casperin/b3d4aeb825dfb8353825) you could use and more documentation on Karma is available at https://karma-runner.github.io.